# Private *new* method, or 'Shadow', but Private

Tags: c#-4.0

It appears clear from Hejlsberg, et. al. 2011 4th Ed. C# Programming Languages that you can make a 'new' function the same name as an existing class member.  I can somewhat see why this might be useful , in some kind of versioning conflict scenario,

But what I don't get is why you would ever want to make the 'new' function or the 'shadow' function;  *private*

Comment: For the same reason you'd want to make any other member private? Imagine a case where a new version of a base class introduces a new public virtual method with the same name as an existing private method you have in your subclass. The minimal change to make your code compile and work exactly as before without any warnings is to explicitly mark it as `new` to show that it's not trying to override the base class method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess my knee jerk reaction here is, why wouldn't one just give it another name then?

Comment: @JonSkeet Can be said that shadows are exclusively the domain of code, that for some untold reason, cannot be refactored?  I personally can't see any use for this feature when working alone on a class hierarchy and it is confusing for me when I try to establish the proper toolset from the available idioms.  Another one that bothers me, for example, is interface re-implementation.  It seems to me; these have no use if you have the source code; you get me?

Comment: No, not always. Another reason might be that you want to provide a more specific return type. See `DbCommand.ExecuteReader` vs `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet What I'm getting at, is that, if you are going in there and changing the source code, putting new here and there, why not just get both source files factor some interface or Helper or whatever out, rename things to be what they actually do and not some vague, broad method name and then be done with.  Otherwise, it seems like you are just 'fixing' things and I have to go into a project, and immediately start using the tools that are used only for fixing broken source bases, it just seems like a waste of time, when you can just do it right, this time, the first time, and the last time.

Comment: What would you do if it's the exact right method name already? Anyway, at this point the question is too broad and/or opinion-based to be a good match for SO...

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you are losing me with that one.  So the return type/ and method parameters signatures don't match, and you still want to use new?  It just feels like there is something orthogonal to both DB and SQL command reader that needs to be 'mixed', 'traited' or otherwise factored right out of there.

Comment: Nope, it's just that the `SqlCommand` is able to provide a more specific view of the returned reader than `DbCommand` can. I have no problem with `ExecuteReader` being "new" in that case. Code that knows it's using a `SqlCommand` can use the extra information. Code that only knows it's using `DbCommand` has to make do with the more basic "view" of the reader.

Comment: The same is true for using explicit interface implementation for `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` when implementing `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you are right.  It's a good way to do it.  SQL and DB that is.  My only qualm would be that I hate to leave some functionality out there so you have to have a runtime cast.  It feels like it breaks the generalism of the whole hierarchy.  If I foreach through something I never want to have to check types and runtime cast anything, ever, really. At least in the patterns I use often.  What I'm saying is the class hierarchy should be responsible for this stuff.  I don't really want "Code [knowing] it's using DbCommand".  The base generalization should be tough enough to avoid it

Answer (score -1):

There are few differences between those.
1. Shadowing is bad programming practice according to OOPs concepts.
2. In shadowing signature could be different.
3. In Shadowing both Derived class methods and Base Class methods are available for use.

In C#, a method in a derived class can have the same name as a method in the base class. You can specify how the methods interact by using the new and override keywords. The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it.

Comment: Why would you make the *new* function private?  Consumers should be able to see your *new* if they want and they are on Version II and know about it and such.  Why would you ever make it private?

Comment: private keyword used to restrict the function so it only visible for who working on it and what do you mean by CONSUMER?

Comment: So if you are working on it, why don't you just give the original function a new, more descriptive and specific name for what it does?  Why would create a second, shadow function/method, to resolve a naming conflict, when ONLY you can see the new shadow?  No other consumer or user of your class can see or use the new shadow, so why would you need to work around the consumer's use of the old function or method name by using *new* shadow, *new* *_private_* shadow at that?